# Does activiti override some function of javascript?

Tags: javascript, activiti

Did anyone try to customize activiti-explorer and meet an issue that some functions of javascript were overrided?

example:

```
var a = {test: [1,2,3]}
JSON.stringify(a);
```

The output will be :

```
"{"test":"[1, 2, 3]"}"
```

But, when I tried on other page (empty page on chrome) with the same code above, the output will be

```
"{"test":[1,2,3]}"
```

(don't have double quote around array). So when I tried $http.post an object which contain array inside, the server received as string instead of array.

Other functions such as reduce (array.reduce in ES6) also have different result with other page.

any ideas?

=== edited ==

When I tried to call

```
delete Array.prototype.toJSON
```

before call `JSON.stringify(a);`, the result is correctly.
But, I'm not sure it is a solution, because i don't know what impact to current app.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is native code so is defined by the JS engine, it seems activiti has implemented this incorrectly as `"{"test":[1,2,3]}"` is correct

Comment: @George is right, JSON has support for arrays with numbers in it so that should not be a string. The key always has to be a string though. This is definitly a bug as you cannot `JSON.parse()` the object back to its original state (which it should)

Comment: @George: yes, "{"test":[1,2,3]}" is what my expectation. but I don't seen where it was overrided.

Comment: @Randy: It happened when I debugged on chrome, I don't think this issue cause by JDK. by the way, I'm using JDK1.8.

Comment: @Randy the log show as `function stringify() { [native code] }`. Could you take a look at my edited on question.

Comment: @QuanVo I'm sorry, my knowledge of both your app and the activiti library are both too sparse to answer this.

Comment: @QuanVo what do you mean by "customize activiti-explorer"? Where do you use those javascript functions?

Comment: I try to add my property to service task when I design on editor-app (it's using angular).

Comment: Currently, To resolve issue stringify, I'm using Object.toJSON instead of JSON.stringify.